# Vuejs and laravel 7 api unauthorized problem on production server

Tags: laravel

I have an application that uses laravel 7 api for the back end with passport for authentication. For the front end i am using vuejs. Everything is work fine in the local machine, but when i upload my application to the production server, i always get ***Error: Request failed with status code 401***,

I googled a lot but found nothing to solve this problem.

I hope you help me.

Comment: Compare your `.env` files as a starting point. Are you using different session drivers, perhaps?

Comment: @ceejayoz my .env files are the same, nothing different.

Comment: Did you create the passport keys? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#deploying-passport These have to be recreated on your server

Comment: I reinstalled passport from scratch, i did everything possible, but no luck, by the way my hosting server is shared